# CUDA sum across blocks

Tags: cuda, gpu

Hello I am new to cuda programming and I got a problem.

I have a variable, let's call **foo** stored in the shared memory of each block with different value from one block to another. And I want only one thread to sum all of them across blocks. I thought to send **foo** to global memory then compute the sum, but is there any function which can do this more quickly?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be faster to have one thread in each block perform an `atomicAdd()` operation, adding the per-block-value to a single, grid-wide variable in global memory.

See the [relevant section](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicadd) of the [CUDA C Programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/).

For a deeper exploration of optimizing reductions (= summation), albeit not necessarily the one you want to perform, have a look at Mark Harris' presentation: [Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).